# EOFError when running a python script in docker container

Tags: python, docker

I have a python script and it takes user input.

```
numbers = input("Enter numbers")
```

I created a docker container but when I run the container I get EOFError: EOF when reading a line. I don't get this error when I run the script without the container. How would I fix this issue?

Comment: Please share your docker run command

Comment: docker run createdcontainer

Comment: try adding the `-it` flags to ur command. `docker run -it createdcontainer`

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell docker to start an *interactive* (`-i`) teletype terminal (`-t`) session

```
docker run --rm -ti your-image
```